# React: how to lift props up to parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and am following a tutorial.

I'm at a stage where I need to lift props up from child to parent components. For the time being I have a simple function on the parent component that just console.logs the retrieved value from the child.

However, it doesn't work. I just get `undefined` in my console.log. I'm unsure what I've done wrong as it appears the same as the example in the tutorial.

Can anyone help me out?

Here's my parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ExpensesFilter from '../ExpensesFilter/ExpensesFilter';
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem";
import Card from "../Ui/Card";
import './Expenses.css';

const Expense = (props) => {

  const yearChangeHandler = (chosenYear) => {
    console.log(chosenYear); // Returns Undefined
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ExpensesFilter onYearChange={yearChangeHandler}/>
      <Card className="expenses">
        <ExpenseItem title={props.items[0].title} amount={props.items[0].amount} date={props.items[0].date} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Expense;
```

And my child component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './ExpensesFilter.css';

const ExpensesFilter = (props) => {
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState('');
  const yearChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const chosenYear = setSelectedYear(event.target.value);
    props.onYearChange(chosenYear); 
  };

  return (
    <div className='expenses-filter'>
      <div className='expenses-filter__control'>
        <label>Filter by year</label>
        <select onChange={yearChangeHandler}>
          <option value='2022'>2022</option>
          <option value='2021'>2021</option>
          <option value='2020'>2020</option>
          <option value='2019'>2019</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpensesFilter;
```

My goal is to console.log the selected year in the parent component. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setSelectedYear` returns `void`. The signatures of `useState` and `setState` are:

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];

type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
```

Try

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './ExpensesFilter.css';

const ExpensesFilter = (props) => {
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState('');
  const yearChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const chosenYear = event.target.value;
    setSelectedYear(chosenYear);
    props.onYearChange(chosenYear); 
  };

  return (
    <div className='expenses-filter'>
      <div className='expenses-filter__control'>
        <label>Filter by year</label>
        <select onChange={yearChangeHandler}>
          <option value='2022'>2022</option>
          <option value='2021'>2021</option>
          <option value='2020'>2020</option>
          <option value='2019'>2019</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpensesFilter;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value which you are passing 'setSelectedYear' directly might not getting set due to async behaviour of useState .

try passing the target.value instead.

```
const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState('');
const yearChangeHandler = (event) => {
  const chosenYear = event.target.value;
  setSelectedYear(chosenYear);
  props.onYearChange(chosenYear); 
};
```